# Trying to append to a URL upon submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

Upon submitting a form I want to append to a URL the value from my input text field. So when the URL is http://localhost:8080/myfile.html?Filters=p1%3D"Hello" and then I submit to the text field p2="Bye" I want the URL to be http://localhost:8080/myfile.html?Filters=p1%3D"Hello"&Filters=p2%3D"Bye"

But for some reason when I press submit the desired URL appears for a second, but upon the page loading the URL becomes http://localhost:8080/myfile.html?Filters=p2%3D"Bye"
I.e the first filter is overwritten. I don't know if it's something to do with clicking submit refreshing the page?

The purpose for this is basically I want to filter results from a list, and be able to add filters like p1="Hello" one by one through a input text box. Perhaps there's a better way of doing this.

HTML:

```
  <form onsubmit="appendFilter()">
    <label for="filters">Add filter:</label><br>
    <input type=text id="filters" name="Filters" placeholder="Filter results..">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
  function appendFilter() {
    var filter = document.getElementById('filters').value
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    searchParams.append("Filters", filter)

    window.history.replaceState({}, '', `${location.pathname}?${searchParams}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not correct.

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); submit()}}>
  // form things
</form>

...

const submit = () => {
  // apply any logic here

  fetch('https://example.com', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      // form values here
    })
  }

  // or window.location.href= // params here
}
```

Comment: oh okay, would you say this is a case for a fetch? I'm not fetching from any external site, I'm just reloading the current page myfile.html but with some additional parameters so that my go program on server side can choose which list items to display. I was also thinking this case would be a get request rather than a post request

Comment: also, is there something missing from this first line? I get an error about tag start not being closed <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault(); submit()}>

Comment: Ah I understand.  Perhaps then the only thing you're missing is the e.preventDefault() because clicking submit will actually submit the form and conflict with your function (I think).  Updated the answer to fix brackets.

Comment: ahh I see thank you, that does work with appending arguments to the url, but now since the page isn't refreshed the server side stuff isn't called so the page isn't reloaded with the updated filters

Comment: Instead of the fetch you can use window.location.href= // set params here.  Or you can use both if you needed to.

Comment: Perfect setting window.location.href works! thank you!